# SQL Query with subquery in Rails ActiveRecord scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, subquery

I want to this query write in rails way.

my_param is variable given to scope

```
select A.id, A.name, B.id
from table1 A 
  join table1_table2 AB on A.id = AB.table1_id
  join table2 B on B.id = AB.table2_id
where my_param in (select AB2.table2_id 
        from table1_table2 AB2
        where AB2.table1_id = A.id)
```

I tried this way (I have joins already and in scope need where clause):

```
scope :by_my_param, ->(my_param) { where my_param => Table1Table2.select(:table2_id).where(table1_id: ...) if my_param.present? }
```

but i dont know how do reference to current id (A.id)

Scope is in model Table1.

Edit:
I have has_many through associations and in controller I use scope this way:

```
Table1.includes(:table2s).by_my_param(param[:my_param])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do eager loading associations by using **includes**:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations

You need to do something like that:

```
table1.includes(:table1_table2).where( my_param: table1_table2: { table1_id: ... } )
```